# Table column toggle UI not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

In jquery mobile v 1.4.5 dynamically add the table rows with column toogle option. Initially toogle the columns, then add the dynamic rows, this hides the selected rows in UI but the toggle popup elements are checked.

```
<table id="tab" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive">
    <thead id="th">
        <tr id="tr1">
            <th>First</th>
            <th data-priority="1">Second</th>
            <th data-priority="2">third</th>
            <th data-priority="3">Fourth</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

See this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/txej8qhj/10/) first click the column button enable the fouth and fifth columns, now click the Add row button the fourth and fifth rows are hidden from UI but again click the colum popup the fourth and fifth columns are checked.

(Fourth and fifth column are hidden because of table refresh,but if remove the refresh then the toogle is not working for dynamic rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try using rebuild instead of refresh:

```
$('#tab').table( "rebuild" );
```

API Doc:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/#method-rebuild

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/txej8qhj/11/)**

Comment: i thing you misunderstood question..this is what i want..http://jsfiddle.net/m1srL7gv/